# What does D.D.P. mean in this inscription? (see image)

Tags: abbreviations, inscription

[image: IMAGE of Inscription from Caserma dei Vigili in Ostia Antica]

I think I got the rest of the inscription figured out. It is a dedication to Marcus Aurelius. **But what does the last abbreviation, D.D.P., stand for?**

The inscription is from a statue base in Caserma dei Vigili
in Ostia Antica.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Sandys's [*Latin Epigraphy: An Introduction to the Study of Latin Inscriptions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vzc9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA298), "D.D.P." stands for:

> **decreto decurionum publice**

The last "P" is sometimes replaced with "P.P." or "PEC PUB": **pecunia publica**.

A [*decurio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decurion_(administrative)) was a public official who, among other things, collected local taxes and was responsible for certain public works.

This is essentially the Latin equivalent of, "Your local tax dollars at work!"

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate that you provided a good source!